# For which $p$ does $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ have a unique maximal proper subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

> Let $p$ be a prime number, $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}$ a primitive $p^\text{th}$ root of unity and $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta).$ Determine those $p$ for which $K$ has a unique maximal proper subfield $k\subsetneq K.$

I'm not confident on this, but here are my thoughts.

We know that $K$ is the splitting field for $x^p-1$. Let $G = \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}).$ Then $$|G| = [K:\mathbb{Q}] = \varphi(p) = p-1.$$ From the Galois correspondence, I believe we are looking for groups $G$ such that $G$ has a minimal nontrivial subgroup. For $p = 2,$ $G = \{e\}$, and for $p=3$, $G\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ whose only proper subgroup is $\{e\}$. Otherwise, for $p\geq 5,$ $2\mid|G|,$ so $G$ has a subgroup of order $2$ by Cauchy. And since all groups of order $2$ are isomorphic, they correspond to subfields of $K$ which are isomorphic. Hence there is a unique maximal subfield of $K$ (up to isomorphism).

Comment: user346096: I wrote my answer predicated on the assumption that ''maximal subfield'' meant ''subfield of maximal degree''. Lubin points out in the comments of my answer that the more common intepretation of ''maximal'' is ''maximal with respect to inclusion'', in which case the answer is a bit different. I've amended my answer to include this interpretation as well. Apologies for any confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is good up until the sentence "since all groups of order $2$ are isomorphic...". The question asks about unique maximal subfields, not unique maximal subfields up to isomorphism, so though you're right that the corresponding field extensions will be isomorphic, $G$ may yet contain distinct subgroups of order $2$, which will correspond to distinct subfields of index $2$. Consider, for example, the Galois extension $K := \mathbb{Q}(\xi, \sqrt[3]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, where $\xi$ is a primitive third root of unity. 
This extension has Galois group $S_{3}$, and $S_{3}$ has $3$ elements (and hence distinct subgroups) of order $2$. This corresponds to the isomorphic (but distinct!) maximal subfields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}), \mathbb{Q}(\xi\sqrt[3]{2}), \mathbb{Q}(\xi^{2}\sqrt[3]{2}) \subset K$.

More data is needed, and it comes from the fact that the $G := \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})$ is *cyclic* of order $p-1$, so the subgroup of order $2$ is in fact unique. The corresponding subfield is the so-called **maximal real subfield**, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta + \zeta^{-1}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$. It is a nice, short exercise to prove that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta + \zeta^{-1})] = 2$ when $p \geqslant 5$, as you describe.

Edit: Prof Lubin points out in the comments that this answer assumes the interpretation that maximal = ''of maximal degree'' and not ''maximal with respect to inclusion''. The latter is likely the intended interpretation of the question, so I will summarize the comments below which give a more complete answer to the question.

As noted above $G := \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})$ is cyclic of order $p-1$, so there is a unique (cyclic) subgroup of order $d$ for each divisor $d$ of $p-1$. This subgroup of order $d$ corresponds with a subfield $k$ of $K$ of index $[K:k] = d$. For two subgroups $H_{1}, H_{2}$ of $G$ of order $d_{1}, d_{2}$ respectively with $d_{1} \mid d_{2}$, we have an inclusion of subgroups $H_{1} \subset H_{2}$, we have a (reverse) proper inclusion $k_{1} \supset k_{2}$ of the corresponding subfields. It is clear, then, that there is a maximal subfield of $K$ of index $q$ for each distinct prime $q$ dividing $p-1$, and these are all such maximal subfields. Since $p-1$ is always divisible by $2$, the only time $K$ has a **unique** maximal subfield is when $p-1$ is a power of $2$, i.e. $p = 2^{n}+1$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: But have you answered the question? In my book, a maximal subfield $k$ would be one with no fields strictly between $k$ and $K$. So then, for $p=7$, since there is a subfield $k$ with $[K:k]=3$, I suppose that that would be maximal as well, even though not of maximum degree over the rationals.

Comment: @Lubin: ah, absolutely fair point. In that case, then, wouldn't the answer be only $p$ such that $p-1$ is divisible by one prime (that is, $2$)? Since the cyclic group of order $p-1$ has a subgroup of order $q$ for each prime $q$ dividing $p - 1$, this means there is a corresponding subfield $k$ of prime index $[K:k] =q$. If I haven't made a mistake here, I'll amend my answer...

Comment: Yeah, I really think that the full answer to OP’s question is primes of form $2^n+1$.

Comment: @Lubin: great, I'll update the answer. Thanks for your comments!